# Return Object value after Filtering an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

I'm trying to get the favorite.user Id and the user. id to match so I could get the product of the individual user added to their favorite here is what I have tried.

```
const product = [
      {
        name: "Product A",
        price: "$100",
        favorites: [
          {
            _id: "60fe705efc8be22860620d3b",
            userId: "3",
            username: "Alif",
            createdAt: "2021-07-26T08:20:46.522Z",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Product B",
        price: "$300",
        favorites: [
          {
            _id: "60fe705efc8be22860620d3b",
            userId: "1",
            username: "John",
            createdAt: "2021-07-26T08:20:46.522Z",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Product C",
        price: "$1300",
        favorites: [
          {
            _id: "60fe705efc8be22860620d3b",
            userId: "1",
            username: "John",
            createdAt: "2021-07-26T08:20:46.522Z",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    
    const user = {
      id: "1",
    };
    
    const favoriteUser = product?.map(({ favorites }) => {
      return favorites.map(({ userId }) => {
        return userId;
      });
    });
    
    const wishlistProduct = product?.filter(() => {
      return user.id === favoriteUser;
    });
    
    console.log(wishlistProduct);
```

I intended it to return both the object Product B and Product C, for example, because they share the same ids. The user.id and the favorite.userId are identical. If you don't understand something, please let me know and I'll try to explain it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use filter with proper predicate

```
product.filter(({ favorites }) => favorites.some(({ userId }) => userId === user.id))
```

```js
const product = JSON.parse(`[{\"name\":\"Product A\",\"price\":\"$100\",\"favorites\":[{\"_id\":\"60fe705efc8be22860620d3b\",\"userId\":\"3\",\"username\":\"Alif\",\"createdAt\":\"2021-07-26T08:20:46.522Z\"}]},{\"name\":\"Product B\",\"price\":\"$300\",\"favorites\":[{\"_id\":\"60fe705efc8be22860620d3b\",\"userId\":\"1\",\"username\":\"John\",\"createdAt\":\"2021-07-26T08:20:46.522Z\"}]},{\"name\":\"Product C\",\"price\":\"$1300\",\"favorites\":[{\"_id\":\"60fe705efc8be22860620d3b\",\"userId\":\"1\",\"username\":\"John\",\"createdAt\":\"2021-07-26T08:20:46.522Z\"}]}]`);

const user = {
  id: "1",
}

const result = product.filter(({ favorites }) => favorites.some(({ userId }) => userId === user.id))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)